# Pandas: Adding column with calculations from other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv with measurements:

```
YY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS    |        x          |          y
2015-12-07 20:51:06:608  |        2          |          4
2015-12-07 20:51:07:609  |        3          |          4
```

and I want to add another column with the square root of the sum of x^2+y^2,
z=sqrt(x^2+y^2)

like this:

```
 YY-MO-DD HH-MI-SS_SSS       |        x          |          y     |     z
    2015-12-07 20:51:06:608  |        2          |          4     |   4.472
    2015-12-07 20:51:07:609  |        3          |          4     |    5
```

Any ideas?

Thank you !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`np.sqrt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html) on the result of the squares:

```
In [10]:
df['z'] = np.sqrt(df['x']**2 + df['y']**2)
df

Out[10]:
   x  y         z
0  2  4  4.472136
1  3  4  5.000000
```

You can also `sum` row-wise the result of `np.square` and call `np.sqrt`:

```
In [13]:
df['z'] = np.sqrt(np.square(df[['x','y']]).sum(axis=1))
df

Out[13]:
   x  y         z
0  2  4  4.472136
1  3  4  5.000000
```